# Switch statement doesn't return the desired value

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am trying to return `'Can drink'` or `'Wait'` based on the ages array but something is wrong with my switch statement, I am getting `'Try again'`.

```js
var yearsArr = [1992, 1980, 2004, 2010];

function getAge(arr, fn) {
    var arrRes = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arrRes.push(fn(arr[i]));
    }
    return arrRes;
}

function calcAge(el) {
    return 2019 - el;
}

var ages = getAge(yearsArr, calcAge);
console.log(ages);

function canDrink(el) {
    switch(el) {
        case el >= 18:
            return 'Drink'
        break;
        case el < 18:
            return 'Wait'
        break;
        default:
            return 'Try again!'
    }
}

var drinkArr = getAge(ages, canDrink);
console.log(drinkArr);
// result = ["Try again!", "Try again!", "Try again!", "Try again!"]
```

Comment: _"**The `switch` statement evaluates an expression, matching the expression's value to a case clause**, and executes statements associated with that case, as well as statements in cases that follow the matching case."_ (Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) / [Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Examples))

Comment: what returns "console.log(ages);"?

Comment: @Eugen, it returns the ages array as follows = [27, 39, 15, 9]

Comment: Note that `>= 18` and `< 18` *almost* cover all possibilities. The only thing that won't match those is if `el` is `NaN` or something (like `"foo"`) that becomes `NaN` when coerced to number. So that's the only time you'll get "try again" (if you make the change [Nina pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56101255/157247)). And although you *can* do that, it doesn't do anything useful compared to just `if`/`else if`. It's longer to write, harder to read, ...

Comment: As a side note, you can substitute `getAge(ages, canDrink)` with `ages.map(canDrink)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not comparing correct values in your switch statement.

Lets imagine using some values, we call `canDrink` with parameter `17`.

```
function canDrink(el) { //Receives 17
    switch (el) { //Handles 17 as main value
        case el >= 18: // 17 >= 18 is false, but true===17 is false
            return 'Drink'
            break;
        case el < 18: // 17<18 is true, but false===17 is false
            return 'Wait'
            break;
        default: // So, none of the conditions matches default executes.
            return 'Try again!'
    }
}
```

How should you adapt this?

```
function canDrink(el) { // el = 17
    switch (true) { // We use true as our main value
        case el >= 18: // 17>=18 is false, so our main value true === false, not executed
            return 'Drink'
            break;
        case el < 18: // 17<18 is true, so true===true, executes this.
            return 'Wait'
            break;
        default:// No need for default.
            return 'Try again!'
    }
}
```

You can check [this working example](https://jsfiddle.net/k3llydev/r62mofbz/).

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `true` as value to check with the results of the `case` parts.

```
switch (true) {    // <---------------------for--+
    case el >= 18: // -> returns a boolean value-+
```

Comment: but how?, can you please explain?

Comment: I used to use the inverse `switch` where you do `switch(true)` and then put each condition as a `case` quite a lot. But then I stopped because I realised there is not much value in this and it's more harm than good. An `if/else` chain signifies intention much more clearly and it's way better for handling the cases. With a `switch(true)` you have to make very sure that only one `case` can evaluate to `true` at a time which can get very annoying very quickly

Comment: From the switch doc: 1. The switch expression is evaluated once. 2. The value of the expression is compared with the values of each case. 3. If there is a match, the associated block of code is executed. - This is why this works. I've never seen this before and will probably never use it. Nevertheless thanks a lot for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

I would use an `if`/`else` statement instead of a `switch` in this case. :-)

```js
// Returns the age for a birthYear
function getAge(birthYear) {
    return (new Date()).getFullYear() - birthYear;
}

// Returns the tapper's response for an age value
function getTapperResponse(age) {
    if (age >= 18) {
        return 'Drink';
    } else {
        return 'Wait';
    }
}

const birthYears = [1992, 1980, 2004, 2010];

const ages = birthYears.map(by => getAge(by));
console.log(ages);

const tapperResponses = ages.map(a => getTapperResponse(a));
console.log(tapperResponses);
```

Comment: I agree - an `if/else` is pretty much always clearer than `switch(true)`. The only change that might be made to make this code behave identically to OP's is to add one more `if` at the start which checks if the value passed in is a number (and not NaN) and return `"Try again!"` in that case. Although, honestly I wouldn't write it that way, I'd just make sure the function is called with the correct type. Or even just leave it - if the input evaluates to `NaN`, then you just refuse to serve them - that's also fine.